# Save image from bar code scanner iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, avcapturesession

I have a barcode scanner I wrote using the some of the new `AVCapture` APIs in IOS7.  Everything works great, but would love to grab the image after I get the met data from the capture output.   The method below is the delegate where I do my lookup on SKU, etc and would like to grab the image as well.  Is it possible to so this from this method?

```
 - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
    {
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specifically answer your question, no, there isn't a way to save an image from a `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` instance.

However, as codingVoldemort's excellent example shows, you can create an `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` instance and add it to your `AVCaptureSession` outputs. Once your app has detected some metadata, you can immediately trigger a capture on that CaptureStillImageOutput instance.

Here's a little more explicit solution using codingVoldemort's initial code as a base:

First, wherever you establish your `AVCaptureSession`, add an `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` to it:

```
_session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

_output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
[_output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[_session addOutput:_output];

_stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
[_session addOutput:_stillImageOutput];
```

Now, in `- captureOutput: didOutputMetadataObjects`, you can capture a still image when the method is triggered:

```
AVCaptureConnection *stillImageConnection = [_stillImageOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
[stillImageConnection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
[stillImageConnection setVideoScaleAndCropFactor:1.0f];
[_stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:AVVideoCodecJPEG
                                                                        forKey:AVVideoCodecKey]];
_stillImageOutput.outputSettings = @{AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoQualityKey:@1};

[stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:stillImageConnection
                                              completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
                                                  if (error) {
                                                      NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
                                                  }
                                                  else {
                                                      NSData *jpegData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
                                                      UIImage *image =[UIImage imageWithData:jpegData];
                                                      //Grabbing the image here
                                                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {

                                                        //Update UI if necessary.


                                                      });


                                                  }
                                              }

 ];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this method:

```
-(void)captureZoomedImage:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    // Find out the current orientation and tell the still image output.
    AVCaptureConnection *stillImageConnection = [stillImageOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    UIDeviceOrientation curDeviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    AVCaptureVideoOrientation avcaptureOrientation = [self avOrientationForDeviceOrientation:curDeviceOrientation];
    [stillImageConnection setVideoOrientation:avcaptureOrientation];
    [stillImageConnection setVideoScaleAndCropFactor:1.0f];
    [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:AVVideoCodecJPEG
                                                                    forKey:AVVideoCodecKey]];
     stillImageOutput.outputSettings = @{AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoQualityKey:@1};

    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:stillImageConnection
                                                  completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
                                                      if (error) {
                                                          [self displayErrorOnMainQueue:error withMessage:@"Take picture failed"];
                                                      }
                                                      else {
                                                          NSData *jpegData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
                                                          UIImage *image =[UIImage imageWithData:jpegData];
                                                          //Grabbing the image here
                                                          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {

                                                            //Update UI if necessary.


                                                          });


                                                      }
                                                  }

     ];

}
```

Comment: Do I call this method inside the one I capture the metadata?  I didn't see how to get the buffer.

Comment: It is a delegate method from `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` protocol. You can read all about it here:

https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks, however would this be called after I received the metadata.  I was wondering if there was any image buffered inside the captureOutput object in the first method.   Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would like to translate Tim's answer to Swift =)
Here is the 1-st section:

```
let session = AVCaptureSession()
var metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
var stillCameraOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
let sessionQueue = dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), nil)

metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: sessionQueue)
        if session.canAddOutput(metadataOutput) {
            session.addOutput(metadataOutput)
        }
session.addOutput(stillCameraOutput)
```

And here is the 2-nd one:

```
var image = UIImage()
let stillImageConnection = stillCameraOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
stillImageConnection.videoOrientation = .Portrait
stillImageConnection.videoScaleAndCropFactor = 1.0
stillCameraOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(stillImageConnection, completionHandler: { (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) in
                    if (error != nil) {
                        print("There are some error in capturing image")
                    } else {
                        let jpegData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)
                        image = UIImage(data: jpegData)!
                    }
                })
```